# MongoCollectionSettings.GuidRepresentation is obsolete, what's the alternative?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB.Driver 2.11.0 and .Net Standard 2.1. To ensure that a database exists and a collection exists, I have the following code:

```
IMongoClient client = ...; // inject a Mongo client

MongoDatabaseSettings dbSettings = new MongoDatabaseSettings();
IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase", dbSettings);

MongoCollectionSettings collectionSettings = new MongoCollectionSettings()
{
    GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard,
};
IMongoCollection<MyClass> collection = db.GetCollection<MyClass>("MyClasses", collectionSettings);
```

In earlier versions of MongoDB.Driver, this code would compile without any warnings. In v2.11.0 I am now getting a warning that "MongoCollectionSettings.GuidRepresentation is obsolete: Configure serializers instead" but I have not been able to find any samples illustrating the new way of setting the Guid serialization format. Does anyone know of other ways to set the serializers for a collection?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to define GuidRepresentation for a specific property, you can do it during the registration of the class map, like so:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(m =>
{
    m.AutoMap();
    m.MapIdMember(d => d.Id).SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
});
```

If you want to do it globally:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
```

Comment: Thanks, the global BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(...) code is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't understand.  What is a class map?

Comment: What if I want to configure this for specific client and not globally?

Answer (score 2):

It was changed in the latest release, see details here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/reference/bson/guidserialization/