# Find an object by GUID using MongoDB Driver with a registered class map

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, guid

How do I find a mongo document by GUID? The c# POCO has an Id property that is stored in the mongo database.

The class map for the POCO is registered and called before a client is configured:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapIdProperty(m => m.MyId)
        .SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
});
```

Now a document is stored in the database correctly by the looks of it:
[image: MongoDB Compass Screenshot]

However, retrieving the document using a builder yields no result:

```
Guid myGuidId = ...;
var filterBuilder = Builders<MyClass>.Filter;
var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(d => d.MyId, myGuidId);
return Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The odd thing is that this query retrieves documents when doing either of these from the start:

- Serialise as string `cm.MapIdProperty(m => m.SimulationId).SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String))`
- Using the obsolete global declaration for GUID serialisation `BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard`

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is related to `guid representation mode` configured by default (V2). You can read about this [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/reference/bson/guidserialization/) or in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264362/mongocollectionsettings-guidrepresentation-is-obsolete-whats-the-alternative/63264791#63264791)

To work with your code, apply configuration as below:

```
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm =>
        {
            cm.AutoMap();
            cm.MapIdProperty(m => m.Value)
                .SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
        });

        var value = Guid.NewGuid();
        var filterBuilder = Builders<MyClass>.Filter;
        var filter = filterBuilder.Eq(d => d.Value, value);
        var db = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("db");

        // Option 1 with MongoCollectionSettings 
        var coll = db.GetCollection<MyClass>("coll1", new MongoCollectionSettings { GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard });
        coll.InsertOne(new MyClass() { Value = value });

        var result = coll.Find(filter).ToList(); // one record returned
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count);

        // Option 2 (Preferable) with BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode.V3
        BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = GuidRepresentationMode.V3;

        coll = db.GetCollection<MyClass>("coll2");
        coll.InsertOne(new MyClass() { Value = value });
        result = coll.Find(filter).ToList();  // one record returned
        Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```